# Code requiring "synchronized" works OK without it

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

This is a program from Herbert Schildt's Java Fundamentals to demonstrate synchronization.The method `sumArray(int[])` is `synchronized`, and that is a requirement for the program to work correctly. However, when I removed the `synchronized` keyword, unexpectedly, the program showed almost the same output, and still gave correct results.
This is the program.

```
class SumArray {
        private int sum;

        int sumArray(int[] nums) {
            sum = 0; // Reset sum.
            for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                sum += nums[i];
                System.out.println("Running total for " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is " + sum);
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }

    class SumThread implements Runnable {
        static SumArray sa = new SumArray();
        Thread thrd;
        int[] a;
        int answer;

        public SumThread(String name, int[] nums) {
            thrd = new Thread(this, name);
            a = nums;
            thrd.start();

        }

        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " starting.");
            answer = sa.sumArray(a);
            System.out.println("Sum for " + thrd.getName() + " is " + answer);
            System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " terminating.");
        }

    }

    public class SyncExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

            SumThread mt1 = new SumThread("Thread #1", a);
            SumThread mt2 = new SumThread("Thread #2", a);

            try {
                mt1.thrd.join();
                mt2.thrd.join();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Output.

```
Thread #1 starting.
Running total for Thread #1 is 1
Running total for Thread #1 is 3
Running total for Thread #1 is 6
Running total for Thread #1 is 10
Running total for Thread #1 is 15
Running total for Thread #1 is 21
Sum for Thread #1 is 21
Thread #1 terminating.
Thread #2 starting.
Running total for Thread #2 is 1
Running total for Thread #2 is 3
Running total for Thread #2 is 6
Running total for Thread #2 is 10
Running total for Thread #2 is 15
Running total for Thread #2 is 21
Sum for Thread #2 is 21
Thread #2 terminating.
```

Is there something wrong with my computer, or are threads supposed to be this strange?

Comment: Try running it unsynchronized a few more times. You'll likely see your results change. That is because you have no guarantee which thread will access the method at any particular time. It could be ordered, like what you see, or not.

Comment: I have run it about 25 times, and I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: Put `thread.sleep(1000);` after `SumThread mt2 = new SumThread("Thread #2", a);` and increase the number of elements in arrays considerably.....It might show you the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with my computer, or are threads supposed to be this strange?

No, Your system is absolutely fine. Yes Threads are supposed to be this strange. Now, there are many possible reasons for this output of your program:

1. Size of Array is very small. So,the operation is executed so fast before the cpu cycle could be handed over to other thread.
2. There is no `Thread.sleep()` within `sumArray` method which may enforce the current thread to leave the execution for a while and let other thread to get the cpu cycle.
3. `mt1.thrd.join();` is executed before `mt2.thrd` is started. This enforces all the threads to wait until `mt1.thrd` finishes its execution.

> How to see the non synchronized behaviour ?

Make the following changes:

```
   int sumArray(int[] nums) {
        sum = 0; // Reset sum.
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum += nums[i];
            try{ 
             Thread.sleep(100);//Make the current thread to sleep for 100 ms
            }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
            System.out.println("Running total for " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is " + sum);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Then another change:

```
int[] a = new int[400];//increase the size of array
for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
a[i] = i;
```

And then ,

```
    SumThread mt2 = new SumThread("Thread #2", a);
    try{
      Thread.sleep(1000);//make to main thread to sleep before mt1.thrd.join() could be called.
     }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    try {
        mt1.thrd.join();
      ....
```

Comment: You're right, putting a call to `Thread.sleep()` in the `for-loop` makes the difference.

Answer (score 6):

You problem is that you have a very small array `int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`.

Thread 1 finishes before even thread 2 starts.

If you try to run with array of 10000 or more elements you might see the difference.

I've run your code with 10000 elements:

> Thread #1 starting.
>
> Thread #2 starting.
>
> Running total for Thread #1 is 1
>
> Running total for Thread #2 is 1
>
> Running total for Thread #1 is 3
>
> Running total for Thread #2 is 5
>
> Running total for Thread #2 is 11
>
> Running total for Thread #2 is 15
>
> Running total for Thread #1 is 8
>
> ..........

So even if your machine shows threads executing sequentially - there is no guarantee that it will this way on every machine and on every program launch.

Also, this way one more mistake is found:

**EDIT**

You've declared sum as a field which should be in fact a local variable. You can see in my output how this effects calculation (sum from one thread is modified by another and so on.)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but it's still the same. Thread#1 finishes before Thread#2 starts.

Comment: With 10,000 elements, keep an eye on the results. That's a huge console output, make sure you're not missing anything. It's very likely JVM gives other thread the opportunity to run before first thread finishes. The idea to understand, however, is that when unsynchronized, you have no control over it.

Comment: -1 . How declaring the sum as local variable would make the OP to see different output?

Comment: What?? See my output: Thread#2: 1 and then 5 instead of expected 3. Because Thread 1 already modified the sum.

Comment: @Tala: local variables of one thread are not modified by other  threads.. They are safely stored in call stack of corresponding thread.It is only the shared fields which are modified by threads..

Comment: @Mac, sa is static: static SumArray sa = new SumArray();

Comment: I am talking about the variable `sum`..Which you had written in your edit that *You've declared sum as a field which should be in fact a local variable ...*. **sum from one thread is modified by another and so on**..The line in bold is absolutely wrong..local variables of one thread is never modified by another thread..

Comment: I said that it should be made local to not be modified by other threads. It is a class field now and one isntance is shared among threads. please pay attention